# Delphi catch Async ADOQuery Exception

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ado

I am opening an ADOQuery asynchronously, and it works as expected, but any exceptions cause the application to hang.  The exception does not get passed back to the main thread.

```html
procedure TfrmMain.actRunExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReportOpening := true;
  with myADOQuery do begin
    ExecuteOptions := [eoAsyncExecute, eoAsyncFetch, eoAsyncFetchNonBlocking];
    OnFetchProgress := ADOQueryFetchProgress;
    OnFetchComplete := ADOQueryFetchComplete;
    try
  Open;
    except
  on E: Exception do MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0); //I expect a timeout here
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ADOQueryFetchComplete(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; const Error: Error; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
begin
  ReportOpening := false;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ADOQueryFetchProgress(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; Progress, MaxProgress: Integer; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure()
 begin
  StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := Format('Progress: %d of %d',[Progress, MaxProgress]);
    end;
    );
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Comment: What exceptions are you talking about? ADO throwing some sort of error or your code in the progress or complete events throwing an error?

Comment: Timeout for example.  For testing purposes I am setting the timeout to 5 seconds and running a long running query.  The query stops at the timeout but I cannot see the exception until I terminate the app

Comment: @MartynA, According to this [link](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1764605)  "// warning about OnFetchxxxx events, they occurr OUTSIDE the main thread, always synchronize", which is why I'm using synchronize

Comment: Putting `Application.ProcessMessages` inside a threaded procedure isn't helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In async mode, you can catch the error in the [`OnExecuteComplete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.OnExecuteComplete) event handler of your [`TADOConnection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection) object. You can use the `EventStatus` and `Error` objects to determine if there was a problem. `Error.Description` will give you the error returned by the database server.

P.S.: please refrain from using `Application.ProcessMessages` in your code as it is not needed since you are using async queries and it can lead to unforeseen event reentry scenarios.

Example:

```
procedure TForm1.ADOConnection1ExecuteComplete(Connection: TADOConnection; RecordsAffected: Integer; const Error: Error;
                                               var EventStatus: TEventStatus; const Command: _Command; const Recordset: _Recordset);
begin
 if EventStatus = esErrorsOccured then
  begin
   memo1.Lines.add(Error.Description);
   // recover from error here
  end;
end;
```